# Using _.partial on function with one argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I'm refactoring code in react.js. I have element that is using partial on Underscore.js _.partial on function that have already one argument Is there any sense to actually do it?

I understand example from the site:

```
var subtract = function(a, b) { return b - a; };
sub5 = _.partial(subtract, 5);
sub5(20);
=> 15
```

But lets say that i have function:

```
onEvent(e){
    this.setState({
        something: {
            property: e
        }
   });
}
```

Why use something like this? (Besides that it doesnt work for me)

Comment: what is this: `{value} => _.partial(setStateOfSomething, value)` ?

Comment: The second example is invalid syntax, what are you trying to achieve with `value`? Destructuring? Also, your function returns nothing so it won't work.

Comment: Edited to show actuall example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question - can you use one functions with one argument with partial.

Yes, you can use `_.partial` with one argument easily enough:

```
// Two arguments
const add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const add5 = _.partial(add, 5);

add5(3); // 8
add5(4); // 9


// One argument
const double = function(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

const doubleFive = _.partial(double, 5);
const doubleTen = _.partial(double, 10);

doubleFive(); // 10
doubleTen(); // 20
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrBaZe?editors=0011

Your second question - "Why use something like this"?

In that particular example, it doesn't make sense at all. `e` is being passed in by a react event, so I'm not sure what you would bind into the partial?

There are plenty of examples why you would use partial in react, but the above isn't one.

Comment: Value of radio button, on change of this radio button.

Comment: Can you expand on your comment?